# Randomness in LIMIT clause in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using LIMIT clause in large tables in BigQuery. I have read that BigQuery distributes job of fetching data to multiple workers and each can read from different part of the data thus I thought that there should be randomness when using LIMIT clause. However, when I tried the same query with LIMIT multiple times, I obtained the same results. I'm curious about how the LIMIT clause work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about Big Query distributing the jobs of fetching data among workers. Each worker reads a different shard of the dataset. For this reason, if you run a query more than once, you might get a different set of results each time.

In your case, you are getting the same set of data, probably, because you are using [BigQuery Cached results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results). This feature allows BigQuery to cache the results from batch and interactive queries in temporary tables for approximately for 24 hours (although, according with the documentation there are exceptions for this time frame, [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#cache-exceptions)).

BigQuery cached results is a feature enabled by default. However, you can disable it in the UI going to: ***More >> Query Settings >> Resource management >> Use cached results***, as you can also see below:

[image]

In addition, it is important to know that caching can not be enable when a *destination table is set*.

You can check the different set of results each time you run a query, disabling the Cached results and using the query below, just as an example:

```
SELECT gender, tripduration  
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` LIMIT 10
```

As a bonus information, I would like to point that, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit-clause-and-offset-clause), the **LIMIT** clause specifies a non negative integer which  defines the amount of rows that will be displayed. However, applying a **LIMIT** does not affect the amount of data read. Thus you are billed for reading all bytes in the entire table and also the query against your free tier quota, you can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs).

Comment: Also, I realized that when LIMIT is applied after ORDER BY, the output is not random. It returns first n rows.

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` clause merely limits the result set output and not the amount of data being read. So it doesn't matter how many workers are employed to scan/read the data. Results will always be the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI, LIMIT limits the amount is data read when you have clustered tables